# Python batch-rename script sending files to root folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-processing, batch-rename

Ok, this is weird and maybe awkward.
I made a script so I could change the end of subtitles files to keep consistency.
Basically it replaces A.X.str to A.Y.str. It worked flawlessly at a single folder.

I decided then to make a recursive version of it so I could do it on any folder I had, regardless if the episodes where together, separated by season or each on an individual path.

I really don't know how or why, but it sent all the files it reached to the root folder I was using until it halted raising a FileExistsError.

The code bit I'm using is:

```
def rewrite(folder, old, new):
    for f in next(os.walk(folder))[2]:
        os.rename(os.path.join(folder, f),
                  os.path.join(path, f.replace(old, new)))
    for f in next(os.walk(folder))[1]:
        x = os.path.join(folder, f)
        rewrite(x, old, new)
```

Where 'old' is "A.X.str", 'new' is "A.Y.str" and folder is the full path of the root folder "C:\Series\Serie Name".

Why doesn't this work as recursive? The first bit of code (First FOR loop) works fine on it's own in a single folder.
Is the problem with the "next" I use to get the names of files and folders?

Answer (score 2):

The code you are showing us is using a `path` variable in the rename destination -- that should be the `folder` variable instead.